# Can I destroy a flame skull with holy water that I've previously used from my component pouch

Tags: dnd-5e, undead

I'm playing a cleric, previously I've always prepared and cast Bless with no issues.

My party meet a flameskull and defeated it, but we do not have holy water.

What can I do to permanently destroy the flameskull?

Is the only solution to Create Holy Water (by spending 1 hour) and then defeat it again? Does the Holy Water in my Spell Component Pouch used to cast Bless count?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I've given your question a pass to help clear up some of the grammar problems with the English. If you think I've changed the meaning of the question in any negative way, feel free to revert my edit.

Comment: @ChibiNya If people don't have the book necessary to answer the question, we don't generally copy out the information for them. [People who don't know the material have no business answering.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5507/should-i-ask-a-poster-to-quote-the-rules-he-or-she-is-confused-about)

Answer (score 12):

### Your spell component pouch counts here if the DM agrees

The description for a spell component pouch says, "...has compartments to hold all the material components and other special items you need to cast your spells, except for those components that have a specified cost..."  (PHB. 151). The description does not say anything about the pouch being magically filled or having an endless stock so it's really just a conveniently designed pouch for holding things your character gathers in the background.

You regularly cast Bless which has the material component, "a sprinkling of holy water", (PHB 219) so that's available in your pouch. The pouch description doesn't say you've got an infinite amount of it so this isn't some loophole to get free Holy Water flasks, it's just a point of convenience.

Flameskulls, "...reform unless they are splashed with holy water...", (MM. 134). Now strictly speaking you need a splash of holy water and your pouch contains some undefined number of sprinklings. Fair rulings would include that you don't have enough holy water (bit boring), that you've got just enough and now have none left to cast bless (add tension), or that a sprinkle is good as a splash and inspiration for your troubles (reward thinking about your resources).

You'll need to talk to your DM to figure out how this will work at your table.

Comment: In some games your component pouch has something like an endless stock or magically fills itself or whatnot, so don't discount the possibility that this may well net you free Holy Water flasks with some time and effort.  In any case, ask your DM.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer The 5e description doesn't saying anything like that. I'm fine discounting options that have no textual basis.

Comment: Isn't holy water an item that actually costs GP in 5e, for a bottle at least.

Comment: @ChibiNya It is, but it is also a spell component you use by the sprinkle so the question.

Answer (score -2):

The questions are "what is a splash?" and "what is a sprinkle?"  I use a splash of cologne, yet the sprinkle from the local Lutheran Church sprinkler for holy water gets me much wetter....    So yeah, up to your GM.  If you have a holy water sprinkler thingy which you use for blessings, then I would say you have enough.  If you use a small vial in a component pouch, then maybe not.

"...has compartments to hold all the material components and other special items you need to cast your spells, except for those components that have a specified cost..." (PHB. 151)."

So using that, you can find a specific cost for a bottle of holy water (25gp 1lb per 5e rules).  Are you using that? or are you using a small vial in your component pouch?  You have to define that.